# Scrollview cutoff at the bottom in ios

Tags: react-native, flexbox, uiscrollview, react-native-ios

I have the following code snippet. Where the last element gets cut-off in ios devices. Can someone help me fix this issue ?

```
  <View >
    <Animated.View
      style={[
        {
          transform: [
            {
              translateX: this.state.x
            }
          ]
        },
        { flexBasis: "100%" }
      ]}
    >
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1}}
        importantForAccessibility="no"
        onScroll={(event) => {
          this.setYOffset(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
        }}
        onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
          this.maxHeight = contentHeight;
        }}
      >
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
          <View style={styles.containerViewStyle} importantForAccessibility="no">
                 <Row />
                 <Row />
                 <Row />
                 <Row />
                 <Row />
          </View>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
      </ScrollView>
    </Animated.View>
  </View>
```

the style for view inside keyboardawarescrollview is as follows:

```
const styles = {
  containerViewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  }
};
```

I have tried setting flex:1 to outer most view. But it doesn't resolve the issue. Can some one help me understand what is the issue here ?

Comment: adding padding bottom to the above style fixes the issue. But i didn't feel its the right way to approach it

Answer (score 2):

Try giving `paddingBottom` to the `Scrollview` in `contentContainerStyle` like:

```
<ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 40 }}
>

    {/* Children */}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I was thinking whether we can achieve the same without using paddingBottom at all.

Comment: I think we would have to provide the padding bottom to get some extra space at the bottom of the scrollview.

Comment: shouldn't flex cover it without providing a padding bottom ?

Comment: No. `Flex` behaves differently with the `ScrollView` as compared to the normal `View`.